# SQL - How to sum only one row above

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have a data set like this one below:

[image: the result column is the sum value of only one row above the current row]

The result column is the sum of the value column of this row and the value column one row above the current row.

Is it possible to write a query for this result?

Comment: What is your database, e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database does not support `LAG`, then we have some other options.  In MySQL, we can try using a correlated subquery to find the lag value:

```
SELECT
    id,
    value,
    COALESCE((SELECT t2.value FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.id < t1.id ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1), 0) result
FROM yourTable t1;
```

A similar query would also work on SQL Server, using `TOP 1` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag your question with a specific [rdbms](/questions/tagged/rdbms), but most modern RDBMSs support the `lag` window function:

```
SELECT value + COALESCE(LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY id), 0) AS result
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` as in:

```
select t.*, 
       (value + lag(value) over (order by id)) as result
from t;
```

If you wanted a value for the first row, you can use `sum()` with a windowing clause:

```
select t.*,
       sum(t.value) over (order by t.id rows between 1 preceding and current row) as result
from t;
```

This generalizes easily to more rows.

Or, if the `id`s have no gaps, then you can use `join`:

```
select t.*, (t.value + tprev.value) as result
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.id = t.id - 1;
```